# How can I utilize SimpleDateFormat with Calendar?

Tags: java, date, calendar, formatting, simpledateformat

I've got GregorianCalendar instances and need to use SimpleDateFormat (or maybe something that can be used with calendar but that provides required #fromat() feature) to get needed output. Please, suggest work arounds as good as permanent solutions.

Comment: For new readers to this question I recommend you neither use `GregorianCalendar` nor `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `LocalDate` or `ZonedDteTime` and also `DateTimeFormatter`. All are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Added the missing step from the JamesKingston's answer. Thanks!

Comment: What is the effect of not to add time zone?

Comment: @kamaci see the comments under JamesKingston's answer. Only matters if you have a calendar object based on a time zone that is different than the system default time zone, and you want it to print in that calendar's time zone. If don't set time zone, it will use default system time zone. If this is the same as the calendar's time zone, then setting the time zone makes no difference. Note that JamesKingston's answer also works -- telling dateFormat which calendar to use means it will know to use the calendar's time zone.

Comment: Doesn't SimpleDateFormat need Locale?

Answer (score 39):

eQui's answer is missing a step

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
#---- This uses the provided calendar for the output -----
dateFormat.setCalendar(cal); 
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: +1, because the answer is the most complete one. Without this method call the default calendar gets used for formatting. (However the question didn't really specify which calendar should be used for formatting.)

Comment: For this case it does not matter, but if you wanted to do things like:
`cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`
`cal.setTime(new Date(record.getMillis()));`
it seems to be.

Comment: Excuse me, why would someone need to set a calendar if he just needs a formatted output?

Comment: To emphasize JamesKingston's previous comment, the answer from eQui (ie. not using dateFormat.setCalendar) will produce the wrong output if the time zone of 'cal' is anything except the system default time zone. To answer @denys-s, it's not just a question of formatting, but also correctness.

Comment: I should clarify that by "correctness", I mean that without the setCalendar, it will convert the calendar to the system default time zone before displaying, which is likely not what you wanted (and particularly not if you don't list the time zone in the format string!). For example, even if you use code to explicitly set a calendar to 2014-05-08, it could potentially get displayed as 2014-05-07 or 2014-05-09, depending on the exact time zone offset.

Comment: I might be missing something, but plz explain me how the default calendar influences the output? I might do something like Calendar cal 2 = new GregorianCalendar(); ... System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime())); where default calendar will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: @Denys-s, in your example it makes no difference. Instead, create a Calendar object, set it to the New Dehli time zone (let's assume that is where your end user is), and set it manually to 2015-01-01 00:00:00 using standard calendar primitives. If your system default time zone is not also set to New Dehli and you don't set the calendar in your dateformat, your output will likely show 2014-12-31 (at least if you are anywhere west of the Indian time zone).

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Answer (score 3):

Calendar.getTime() returns a Date which can be used with SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3):

Simply call `calendar.getTime()` and pass the resulting `Date` object to the `format` method.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. So not `GregorianCalendar`. Since a `GregorianCalendar` was holding all of date, time of day and time zone, the general modern substitute for it is `ZonedDateTime`.

You didn’t specify what *needed output* would be. I am assuming that we want output for a human user. So use Java’s built in localized format for the user’s locale:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
                .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("es"));
```

I specified Spanish language just as an example. If you want to use the JVM’s default locale, you may either specify `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` or leave out the call to `withLocale()` completely. Now formatting a `ZonedDateTime` is straightforward (and simpler than it was with a `GregorianCalendar`):

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
            2011, 4, 11, 19, 11, 15, 0, ZoneId.of("Australia/Perth"));
    System.out.println(zdt.format(FORMATTER));
```

Output from this example:

> 11 de abril de 2011, 19:11:15 AWST

In case you only need dates and no time of day or time zone, you need two changes:

1. Use `LocalDate` instead of `ZonedDateTime`.
2. Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()` instead of `.ofLocalizedDateTime()`.

### What if I really got a `GregorianCalendar`?

If you got a `GregorianCalendar` from a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time, convert to `ZonedDateTime`:

```
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(
            TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Perth")));
    cal.set(2011, Calendar.APRIL, 11, 19, 11, 15);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = cal.toZonedDateTime();
```

Then proceed as before. Output will be the same.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.