# SimpleDateFormat subclass adds 1900 to the year

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I've created a couple of subclasses of `SimpleDateFormat` to simplify dealing with an Azure feed I'm talking to on Android.  One of them is as follows:

```
public class ISO8601TLDateFormat extends SimpleDateFormat {

    private static String mISO8601T = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

    public ISO8601TLDateFormat() {
        super(mISO8601T);
    }

    public ISO8601TLDateFormat(Locale inLocale) {
        super(mISO8601T, inLocale);
    }
}
```

As you can see the intention is to produce or interpret dates looking like

2012-03-17T00:00:00.000+0100

which is what the Azure service is expecting.  However, when I feed in `Date` objects constructed from a `DatePicker` thus:

```
mDate = new Date(mDatePicker.getYear(), mDatePicker.getMonth(), mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
```

the output of the `ISO8601TLDateFormat` is

3912-03-17T00:00:00.000+0100

As you can see, the year is 1900 more than I, or anyone else not **from the future**, would need.  I've scrutinized the `Date` object on its entire journey to the Azure feed system and it reports its date is 2012, which is what I would have expected.  Why is the `SimpleDateFormat` breaking?

Comment: It's likely there's a `Date` involved *somewhere*, because its year is year-1900.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here... we need to know the specific calls you're making to your SimpleDateFormat, to produce your erroneous output and how it is being initialized, etc etc.

Comment: I've got an answer (below) but I will clarify how I wrongly constructed my `Date` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the constructors of `Date` do not receive what you expect. Taken from the java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

```
public Date(int year,
            int month,
            int date)
Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).
Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents midnight, local time, at the beginning of the day specified by the year, month, and date arguments.
Parameters:
year - the year minus 1900.
month - the month between 0-11.
date - the day of the month between 1-31.
```

You need to keep in mind that you construct a date with `0, 0, 1` being 1st of January 1900.

Comment: Thank you—I assume, then, that `Date#getYear()` also provides you with the year minus 1900?  (It's certainly giving me 2012).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear(). Just read the docs and you will find you are right.

Comment: Mind if I add this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621825/how-can-i-utilize-simpledateformat-with-calendar to your answer?