# How to parse from week/year to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: java, string, date, calendar

I'm trying to parse a String that contains week/year information to a normal dd-mm-yyyy format

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class FromWeektoDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    gregorianCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
    gregorianCalendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);

     String SemaineYear[] = "20/2018".split("/");


         int s = Integer.parseInt(SemaineYear[0]);
         int a = Integer.parseInt(SemaineYear[1]);
      int numWeekofYear = s;  //INPUT
       int year = a;         //INPUT

    gregorianCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR , year);
    gregorianCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR , numWeekofYear);

  Date date = new Date();

     date.setDay(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) );   
     date.setMonth(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)  + 1 );
     date.setYear(gregorianCalendar.get
                        (Calendar.YEAR));

    System.out.println(date);
}
}
```

but I'm getting this error :

> ```
> /tmp/java_5kSPR0/FirstDayofWeek.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
>          date.setDay(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) );   
>              ^
>   symbol:   method setDay(int)
>   location: variable date of type Date
> /tmp/java_5kSPR0/FirstDayofWeek.java:27: warning: [deprecation] setMonth(int) in Date has been deprecated
> ```

Comment: This can produce one of seven possible dates.  Which one would you like?

Comment: Also, you really should avoid using the legacy `java.util.Date` (and any of its friends).  The `java.time` package is so much cleaner.

Comment: @JoeC I want to get my date like this dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: For example: the second week of 2019.  Assuming a European locale, this can be the 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, or 13th of January.  Which one of those would you like?

Comment: It's not really important to know which day exactly! I just need to get a day from this week

Comment: Your week scheme — Sunday is first day of week and the week 1 is the first week with at least 4 days in the new year — seems nonstandard. Is this scheme used in some real-life locale?

Comment: The date-time classes that you use — `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar` and `Date` — are poorly designed and long outdated. I recommend you don’t use them. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care what day within the week you want, you can simply start from New Year's Day and add as many weeks as you like:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1).plusWeeks(weekOfYear - 1)
```

For your example (20th week of 2018), this gives me `2018-05-14`.

Comment: You can create a `DateTimeFormatter` which will format it to your heart's content.

Comment: This assumes that January 1 is always in week 1. If I understood correctly that the asker wants a minimum of 4 days in week 1, this will be true for 2018 (6 days in week 1), but will not be true for all years. It’s good to show the use of `LocalDate` from java.time.

Comment: At least 4 days of the year in week 1 implies that January 4 is always in week 1, so you may use that as a starting point for counting weeks instead of January 1.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

java.time, the modern Java date and time API, can do that.

```
    // In Malta weeks begin on Sunday, and there must be at least 4 days
    // of a week in a year for it to be week 1 of that year
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.forLanguageTag("mt"));

    DateTimeFormatter yearWeekFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(wf.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 2)
            .appendLiteral('/')
            .appendValue(wf.weekBasedYear(), 4)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, wf.getFirstDayOfWeek().getValue())
            .toFormatter();

    String weekString = "20/2018";
    LocalDate sundayOfWeek20 = LocalDate.parse(weekString, yearWeekFormatter);
    System.out.println(sundayOfWeek20);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2018-05-13

To format into 13/05/2018 use another `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    System.out.println(sundayOfWeek20.format(dateFormatter));
```

> 13/05/2018

I interpreted from your code that your require a week scheme where the week starts on Sunday and there are at least 4 days in the first week. The `WeekFields` class is used for defining such a scheme. If your requirement comes out of a specific locale (Malta or Ireland), I recommend using that locale for defining the `WeekFields` object to use, as I do in the snippet above. If, on the other hand, your requirement doesn’t come from some locale, it’s better to specify it more directly:

```
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 4);
```

I am using java.time’s built-in parsing mechanism through `LocalDate.parse`. No need to hand parse or otherwise reinvent the wheel. To have the formatter understand our week scheme I pass `TemporalField` objects that I get from the `WeekFields` to `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appenValue`. To parse into a `LocalDate` we need to add a day of week (even though you said you don’t care which). I use the call to `parseDefaulting` for that.

Frankly I was surprised to see how flexible java.time was to meet your requirements. Even though I knew already that it is a pleasure to work with it.

The date-time classes that you used — `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar` and `Date` — are poorly designed and long outdated. I recommend you don’t use them.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [getTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) to get Date object

```
Date date =  gregorianCalendar.getTime();
```

> Returns a Date object representing this Calendar's time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch").

Or use [SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621825/how-can-i-utilize-simpledateformat-with-calendar)  for parsing specific format

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(gregorianCalendar.getTimeZone());
```